# How to name or rename an EIP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Somehow, at some point, I created 2 EIPs and gave them names (they have names in the EC2 UI).

[image]

But now I cannot figure out, or find in the docs, how to name EIPs either when creating them or after creating them - how do you do it (answer can be through the AWS CLI instead)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the name of an elastic IP address set or change the "Name" tag, which is in the lower portion of the window. Note that the tag Name is case sensitive.

[image]

Comment: Note that this is case sensitive! "name" does not work.

Comment: Yep, that's why I wrote it in upper case and said "Note that it is case sensitive." I will see if I can make that even more clear.